# Visual Studio 2008 Web Setup Project Issue

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, installation, web-setup-project

I have created a web setup project in Visual Studio 2008 for multiple environments, DEV, QA, UAT, and PROD.  I set all four of my file system web.config files to the following conditions and targetname:

```
 - Condition: DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT="Development", TargetName: web.config
 - Condition: DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT="QA", TargetName: web.config
 - Condition: DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT="UAT", TargetName: web.config
 - Condition: DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT="Production", TargetName: web.config
```

SourcePath is set to my local machine where all four web.config files are located and named DEV.web.config, QA.web.config, UAT.web.config, and Production.web.config.
I have a user interface with four radio buttons with labels and values that match my file names, ButtonProperty is set to DEVELOPMENT_ENVIRONMENT, and DefaultValue is set to Development.

During the install when I select an environment other than development, like QA or UAT, all files are installed except the web.config.  Any ideas what I missed or may be causing this issue?

Comment: What are the exact radio button values?